# telnet from localhost to AWS Cassandra fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, telnet

I am trying to telnet from my local host to AWS Cassandra. But I am getting,
Connection refused telnet: Unable to connect to remote host.

I am trying to run as below
telnet IP_address 9042

I saw somewhere that I should change rpc_address: in /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml. But I don't see this parameter in this file.
If you have fixed this issue please help me.

Comment: Yes. Opened with custom TCP on 9042.

Comment: telnet to any port doesn't work from localhost